# nginx not reachable from outside with SELINUX disabled

Tags: nginx, centos6

I've just installed a CentOS 6.5 server and I've installed on it nginx.

I've disabled SELINUX and restarted the server but nginx is still not reachable from other servers except for the host itself.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there was a rule in IPTABLES that was blocking all incoming connections.

```
iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers
iptables -D INPUT <N>
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

has solved the problem.